# Bug in System.Net.Http.StringContent on Windows 11?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I have the below code that has been running just fine for a couple years now on .NET 6.  My development environment is a Windows 10 VM and Visual Studio 17.4.2.  I recently set up a new Windows 11 VM with Visual Studio 17.4.2.  This same .NET 6 code will compile just fine on that new dev machine but when I run it in Visual Studio, the creation of StringContent is failing.  It’s not throwing an exception, but I can clearly see when debugging that the StringContent has no content byte array, just the headers.  On both dev machines, System.Net.Http.dll is the same exact version.  Here the info on that:

Assembly Name: System.Net.Http

Assembly Version: 6.0.0.0

File Version: 6.0.1122.52304

Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.11\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Http.dll

Here is my code:

```cs
var requestUriWithQuery = string.Concat(requestUri, "?", query);

var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUriWithQuery);

requestMessage.Content = httpContent;
```

I was expecting the code to execute successfully on the Windows 11 dev machine as it does on the Windows 10 dev machine.  I've spent 8+ hours on this and am stumped on what's wrong.

[image: Debugging on older VM - Windows Server 2019]

[image: Debugging on newer VM - Windows 11]

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Here is a minimal reproducible example.  You can put this into a new C# Console App (.NET 6) and run it without adding any dependencies.  Earlier I stated that it works fine on Windows 10 but that was a mistake.  It is a Windows Server 2019 VM – with Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.2).  On my new Windows 11 VM, also with Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.2), the StringContent object is not constructed properly and this is causing my application to fail.  Notice in the screenshots the p1StringContent object.  They are different on the different machines yet the code and .NET Framework are identical.

Comment: Apparently I cannot upload the screenshots.  Here is the code:


Person p1 = new Person();
p1.FullName = "John Doe";
p1.Age = 19;

string p1Serialized = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(p1);
StringContent p1StringContent = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(p1Serialized, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
byte[] p1Bytes = p1StringContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

Console.WriteLine(p1Bytes.Length);
Console.ReadLine();

public class Person
{
    public string? FullName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

}

Comment: You can edit the question to include images and the code. So what does Console.WriteLine() output and what is expected?

Comment: After more testing, I don’t think it’s an OS issue.  I’ve installed VS 2022 on a couple different new VM’s (Win 10, Win Server 2022) and they both behave like my new Win 11 VM – they don’t properly construct the StringContent object.  The Console.WriteLine is yielding 32 which seems correct – and that’s what I get on my older Win Server 2019 VM.  However, the StringContent object is getting constructed incorrectly as can be seen in the Quick Watch when debugging.  The screenshots show that clearly.  I will try to attach them to the original question (sorry, not familiar with Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in the two screenshots is just that on the first system non-public members are hidden by default in the debugger while they are shown by default on the second machine.

You can view the non-public members on the first machine by clicking on the little arrow in front of the "non-public members" text.

[image: click on the little arrow in front of "non-public members" in the debugger view]

The difference between the two machines is the setting **"Just my Code"** in the debugger settings. It influences (among other things) whether non-public members of classes that are not part of your current solution are shown in the debugger by default or not.

[image: Setting "Enable Just My Code" in the Visual Studio Debugging Options]

So, the difference you see is just different visualization by the debugger. The data in the `StringContent` object is the same and there doesn't seem to be a real problem.

If you see a problem at run-time, you should try to find more details about why it happens and post a new question with more details on the actual problem.